# Monogame sprite alpha blending

Tags: c#, monogame, alphablending, spritebatch

At the moment, I am having a 2D grid of terrain textures, which I am drawing using the standard XNA/Monogame `spritebatch.Draw()` function. In order to have smoother transitions between adjacent but different terrain textures, I would like to blend textures within a certain area (say 3x3) around a center texture. The further a neighboring texture is away, the smaller should be its impact on the final image.

E.g., a (3x3) weighting matrix `weight` around a central texture at (1,1) could look something like this:

```
0.3 0.5 0.3
0.5 1.0 0.5
0.3 0.5 0.3
```

Basically, a simple problem. However, I am currently staggering with the different blending modes offered and their functionality. My initial idea was to just use `BlendState.AlphaBlend` together with

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Tex2D, TargetRec, new Color(Color.White, weight[x,y] / SumOfWeights));
```

The white color should give me the original texture colors, the alpha value `weight[x,y] / SumOfWeights` would in the end add up to 1. Instead, what I get is a very bright image plus the background shining through.

A better result can be achieved, when also setting the tinting Color to a gray with the same value as the alpha channel. Again, the background is shining through, though, when using more than 2 textures.

There must be a systematic error in my concept, but I am momentarily unable to find it. Please point out my mistake & thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your question correctly. You want to implement a similar functionality to the "fog of war" from old RTS games?

Comment: The application does not matter so much. Momentarily, I do simply not understand the process of alpha blending. Why do I still see background, if the combined alpha (and tint color) values of the foreground are 1.0f?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is the initialization of the spritebatch and order of objects for which you draw. Are you using a depth level or "first called, first drawn" approach?

Comment: Are your sprites pre-multiplied?  If you aren't familiar with how premultiplying works then the alpha channel will not work how you expect it to.  If you don't know if your sprites are premultiplied then they probably aren't.  I believe monogame expects premultiplied sprites by default when using SpriteBatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Tex2D, TargetRec, Color.White * weight[x,y]);
```

This is the proper way to draw things transparently when SpriteBatch is using premultiplication. The alpha channel works differently when drawing with premultiplication.  The basic change you need to make is to multiply the color by the transparency instead of setting the alpha channel of the color.

Here is some more information. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx